# How to control the serial GPIO pin of Raspberry Pi via an Apache web sever

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, uart, gpio

I would like to send data from [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) to [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) via the GPIO serial port by using the Apache server running on Raspberry Pi. I connected the TX pin of RPI to a 3.3 V-to-5 V level shifter and its output to the RX Arduino PIN.

To send data from Raspberry Pi to Arduino I used the following C program that I recompiled for Raspberry Pi, and it works fine. I renamed the executable code `SendUART`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>   //Used for UART
#include <fcntl.h>    //Used for UART
#include <termios.h>  //Used for UART
#include <string.h>

main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    //----- TX BYTES -----
    unsigned char tx_buffer[20];
    unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;
    int lx;

    //-------------------------
    //----- SETUP USART 0 -----
    //-------------------------
    //At bootup, pins 8 and 10 are already set to UART0_TXD, UART0_RXD (ie the alt0 function) respectively
    int uart0_filestream = -1;

    //OPEN THE UART
    //The flags (defined in fcntl.h):
    //    Access modes (use 1 of these):
    //        O_RDONLY - Open for reading only.
    //        O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing.
    //        O_WRONLY - Open for writing only.
    //
    //    O_NDELAY / O_NONBLOCK (same function) - Enables nonblocking mode. When set read requests on the file can return immediately with a failure status
    //                                            if there is no input immediately available (instead of blocking). Likewise, write requests can also return
    //                                            immediately with a failure status if the output can't be written immediately.
    //
    //    O_NOCTTY - When set and path identifies a terminal device, open() shall not cause the terminal device to become the controlling terminal for the process.
    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);        //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    if (uart0_filestream == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
        printf("Error - Unable to open UART.  Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
    }

    //CONFIGURE THE UART
    //The flags (defined in /usr/include/termios.h - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/termios.h.html):
    //    Baud rate:- B1200, B2400, B4800, B9600, B19200, B38400, B57600, B115200, B230400, B460800, B500000, B576000, B921600, B1000000, B1152000, B1500000, B2000000, B2500000, B3000000, B3500000, B4000000
    //    CSIZE:- CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8
    //    CLOCAL - Ignore modem status lines
    //    CREAD - Enable receiver
    //    IGNPAR = Ignore characters with parity errors
    //    ICRNL - Map CR to NL on input (Use for ASCII comms where you want to auto correct end of line characters - don't use for bianry comms!)
    //    PARENB - Parity enable
    //    PARODD - Odd parity (else even)
    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;  //<Set baud rate
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
    p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
    strcpy(tx_buffer, argv[1]);
    lx=strlen(tx_buffer);


    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        int count = write(uart0_filestream, &tx_buffer[0], 10);  //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
        if (count < 0)
        {
            printf("UART TX error\n");
        }
    }
    //----- CLOSE THE UART -----
    close(uart0_filestream);
}
```

Then I used a PHP script (test.php) to handle the software via the "system" command:

```
<?php
     $mes = "0123456789";
     $retval = 0;
     $last_line = 0;
     echo($mes);
     $SndMsg = "/var/www/SendUART " . $mes;
     $last_line = system($SndMsg, $retval);
     echo $last_line
?>
```

And I executed it via the command line:

```
php -f test.php
```

The string is correctly received by the Arduino (I developed a simple [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) for Arduino that turns on the onboard LED if all characters are received from the Rx pin).

Then I called the PHP script via the Apache web server, writing in the address bar:
http://192.168.1.103/test.php

where 192.168.1.103 is the IP address of the Raspberry Pi and `test.php` is the PHP script. Of course, both `test.php` and the SenUART program are stored in the same folder /var/www/, but the following error is shown in the browser:

> 0123456789Error - Unable to open UART. Ensure it is not in use by another application

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Is the UART enabled as a serial console by any chance?  Are you use raspbian?

http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/io-pins-raspbian/uart-pins

Comment: The UART is enabled. I'm using raspbian.

Comment: You must disable the UART's use as a serial console.  see previously posted link.

Answer (score 1):

The user running your webserver probably doesn't have access to the UART.  You can quickly test this by configuring Apache to run as root by setting the following in `httpd.conf`:

```
User root
```

Since it's not a good idea to run a webserver as root, you'll want to find out what user Apache usually runs as on your system (probably `www`) and give that user permission to use the serial port.  Something like this may work:

```
chown :www /dev/ttyAMA0
chmod g+rw /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Alternatively, you may just need to add user `www` to a group like `callout`:

```
useradd -G callout www
```

Adjust for your specific system.